# Return a `Comparator` from another function

Tags: java, comparator

Firstly, please let me clear that I'm limited by the API design so please don't change the API,however, private functions can be added.

```
public class Point implements Comparable<Point> {

    public Point(int x, int y)              // constructs the point (x, y)
    public void draw()                      // draws this point
    public void drawTo(Point that)          // draws the line segment from this point to that point
    public String toString()                // string representation

    public int compareTo(Point that)        // compare two points by y-coordinates, breaking ties by x-coordinates
    public double slopeTo(Point that)       // the slope between this point and that point
    public Comparator<Point> slopeOrder()   // compare two points by slopes they make with this point
}
```

The problem arises when I try to override the compare function in the `slopeOrder()` method. I tried to call the `compare()` method in the `slopeOrder()` function but since I don't have any parameters in the API I couldn't.

Please suggest some solutions to return a `Comparator<Point>` from the `slopeOrder()` method.

Comment: looks like ASM ;) with those line comments ;)

Comment: Do you need to call compare? If the points are comparable, why would you need that comparator. It seems like the comparator you should return should define another ordering.

Comment: It's one of the assignments on coursera (algs4), nailed the logic part but this is the first time I'm dealing with the Comparator interface.

Comment: @JornVernee I need to compare slopes so as to pass it later to a sorting fuction, I must follow the API.

Comment: I'm a little fuzzy on the difference between having a function to return a Comparator and just having your class implement the Comparator interface. Is anyone able to help me out on that? Is it because we want to compare two other instances with the current instance?

Comment: princeton algorithm part I haha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can instantiate a `Comparator<...>` using a lambda expression:

```
public Comparator<Point> slopeOrder() {
    return (a, b) -> {
        // code here
    };
}
```

Here, `a` and `b` are the points to be compared.

Or if you're below java 8, you'd have to use an anonymous class:

```
public Comparator<Point> slopeOrder() {
    return new Comparator<Point>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Point a, Point b) {
            // code here
        }
    };
}
```

If the `Comparator` is statless, you could create 1 instance and save it as a `static final` field, and just always return that instance.

Of course you can also take the long way around and create a new class that implement `Comparator<Point>`, and instantiate that class instead.

Comment: That worked just fine thanks! I'll look into lambda expressions.

Comment: Comparators are always *stateless*. This particular comparator is contextual, i.e. it cannot be a singleton, because it uses the current `Point` to calculate the slopes to be compared.

Answer (score 11):

Since the description of the `slopeOrder()` method is:

> compare two points by **slopes** they make with **this** point

That means you need to compare the values returned by calling `slopeTo(Point that)` on each object. Given that the return value of that method is a `double`, it means that you need to call [`Double.compare()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare-double-double-).

In pre-Java 8, you'd implement it using an anonymous class:

```
public Comparator<Point> slopeOrder() {
    return new Comparator<Point>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Point o1, Point o2) {
            return Double.compare(slopeTo(o1), slopeTo(o2));
        }
    };
}
```

In Java 8, that's much simpler to write as a lambda expression:

```
public Comparator<Point> slopeOrder() {
    return (o1, o2) -> Double.compare(slopeTo(o1), slopeTo(o2));
}
```

Or using a method reference:

```
public Comparator<Point> slopeOrder() {
    return Comparator.comparingDouble(this::slopeTo);
}
```

In all cases, the `slopeTo()` calls are made on the `this` object of the `slopeOrder()` call.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two points with `this` point.

```
public Comparator<Point> slopeOrder() {
    final Point that = this;
    return new Comparator<Point>() {

        public int compare(Point o1, Point o2) {
            return Double.compare (o1.slopeTo(that) - o2.slopeTo(that));
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Don't use `d1 - d2` for comparing `double` values. Use `Double.compare(d1, d2)`.